# HOWTO PGP encrypt a byte array

Tags: .net, encryption, pgp

I have this PGP encryption sample that reads from a file and encrypts without issues.

I am trying to convert the code to encrypt from a byte array instead of from file.

The original sample code and my conversion attempt is given below.

The output from my converted code is wrong.

Please what have I missed?

**Sample code** - *reads from file and encrypts with PGP*

```
Public Sub EncryptAndSign(outputStream As Stream, unencryptedFileInfo As FileInfo)
    Using encryptedOut As Stream = ChainEncryptedOut(outputStream)
        Using compressedOut As Stream = ChainCompressedOut(encryptedOut)
            Dim signatureGenerator As PgpSignatureGenerator = InitSignatureGenerator(compressedOut)
            Using literalOut As Stream = ChainLiteralOut(compressedOut, unencryptedFileInfo)
                Using inputFile As FileStream = unencryptedFileInfo.OpenRead()
                    WriteOutputAndSign(compressedOut, literalOut, inputFile, signatureGenerator)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Shared Function ChainLiteralOut(compressedOut As Stream, file As FileInfo) As Stream    
    Dim pgpLiteralDataGenerator As New PgpLiteralDataGenerator()

    Return pgpLiteralDataGenerator.Open(compressedOut, PgpLiteralData.Binary, file)
End Function

Private Shared Sub WriteOutputAndSign(compressedOut As Stream, literalOut As Stream, inputFile As FileStream, signatureGenerator As PgpSignatureGenerator)
    Dim length As Integer = 0

    Dim buf(BufferSize - 1) As Byte

    length = inputFile.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
    Do While length > 0
        literalOut.Write(buf, 0, length)

        signatureGenerator.Update(buf, 0, length)

        length = inputFile.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
    Loop

    signatureGenerator.Generate().Encode(compressedOut)
End Sub
```

**My converted code** - *PGP encrypt a byte array*

```
Public Sub EncryptAndSign(outputStream As Stream, unencryptedData As Byte())
    Using encryptedOut As Stream = ChainEncryptedOut(outputStream)
        Using compressedOut As Stream = ChainCompressedOut(encryptedOut)
            Dim signatureGenerator As PgpSignatureGenerator = InitSignatureGenerator(compressedOut)
            Using literalOut As Stream = ChainLiteralOut(compressedOut, unencryptedData)
                WriteOutputAndSign(compressedOut, literalOut, unencryptedData, signatureGenerator)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Shared Function ChainLiteralOut(compressedOut As Stream, data As Byte()) As Stream
    Dim pgpLiteralDataGenerator As New PgpLiteralDataGenerator()

    Return pgpLiteralDataGenerator.Open(compressedOut, PgpLiteralData.Utf8, "enc_" & Now.Ticks, Now, data)
End Function

Private Shared Sub WriteOutputAndSign(compressedOut As Stream, literalOut As Stream, inputData As Byte(), signatureGenerator As PgpSignatureGenerator)
    Dim length As Integer = inputData.Length
    Dim buf = inputData

    literalOut.Write(buf, 0, length)
    signatureGenerator.Update(buf, 0, length)

    signatureGenerator.Generate().Encode(compressedOut)
End Sub
```